# How to stop a php element from loading on a specific page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, element

So... the website i'm working on have three elements that they use on every webpage, the header, footer and a side element (sideLeft). I can access all the files and can even create templates for the post I want to make. The problem is it auot loads those 3 elements so I was hoping that there is a snippet of code that I can implement either into the element file or on the template that would cause it to not laod the sideLeft.el.php element just for that specific webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply not including the part you don't want to be loaded on that page?

Answer (score 0):

Get the pagename from the url and put condition in sideleft.el.php to not render.

```
<?php>
$urlPath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strpos($urlPath, 'pagename') > 0)
{
   // dont display
}else{
  //display
}

</?>
```

Comment: This code is currently already in there...<?php 

if($this->view->elements->basket instanceOf element) {
 e($this->view->elements->basket->render());
}
if($this->view->elements->lastSearch instanceOf element) {
 e($this->view->elements->lastSearch->render());
}  

Do I need to edit that or can I just add in your php code with the pagename put in?

Comment: just add and put the page name from url